# JAVA. Кастомный логгер класс

Tags: java

Обрабатываю данные между сервером и клиентом, есть момент когда в случае неверных данных и других ошибок необходимо писать лог на сервере.

Проблема в том, что подключение логгера в нужном классе (в примере вызываю внутри SomeClass) и вызов метода записи в него ничего не дает. Однако вызов метода логирования в самом классе логгера работает отлично.

Самое печальное, что дебажить код не могу, из-за работы всего этого дела внутри SAP портала. Некоторые типы также саповские, но они унаследуют от стандартных java классов. Думаю проблема не в SAP, а в каких-то стандартных моментах вызова и оформления

Код двух классов:

```
public class Log extends AbstractPortalComponent {
    private static Location fLocation = Location.getLocation(Log.class);

    void writeLog(IPortalComponentRequest request, IPortalComponentResponse response, String msg, Boolean email, Boolean isError) {
        FileLog myFileLog = new FileLog(Log.fFolder + File.separator + "log.log", "UTF8", 1000000, 10, new ListFormatter());

        //clear all logs
        fLocation.removeLogs();
        //adding log type to location
        fLocation.addLog(myFileLog);
        //push into logs all messages (info, dbug, warn, error)
        fLocation.setEffectiveSeverity(Severity.ALL);

        if (isError == true) {
            fLocation.errorT(msg);
        }
    }
}


public class SomeClass extends AbstractPortalComponent {
    private static Log logger = new Log();

    protected void writeResponse(IPortalComponentRequest request, IPortalComponentResponse response, String responseBody) {
        logger.writeLog(request, response, "ERROR", true, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы уверенны, что метод логера вообще вызывается? Что не происходит какого-то эксепшена?

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, когда начал смотреть все ли охватывается проверками и смотреть системные логи нашел реальную ошибку которая касалась обращения к SAP сервисам